# Strip unwanted values from JSON

Tags: php, json

I have the following text that I want to strip out and grab the data.

```
(function() {})({
    "Data": {
        "Status": "SUCCESS",
        "Name": "Facebook Inc",
        "Symbol": "FB",
        "LastPrice": 31.91,
        "Change": -1.12,
        "ChangePercent": -3.39085679685135,
        "Timestamp": "Fri May 25 16:00:05 UTC-04:00 2012",
        "MarketCap": 20214729720,
        "Volume": 37189630,
        "ChangeYTD": 0,
        "ChangePercentYTD": 0,
        "High": 32.95,
        "Low": 31.11,
        "Open": 32.9
    }
})
```

I also have the following code that IS working with google api which will be leaving us in October this year.

```
<?php

//Obtain Quote Info
$quote = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:'  . $stock . '');

//Remove CR's from ouput - make it one line
$json = str_replace("\n", "", $quote);

//Remove //, [ and ] to build qualified string  
$data = substr($json, 4, strlen($json) -5);

//decode JSON data
$json_output = json_decode(utf8_decode($data));

// get the last price
$perc = $json_output->c;
$last = $json_output->l;
$date = $json_output->lt;
$name = $json_output->t;
?>
```

For whatever reason I cannot figure out how to get the other to work with my code.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What characters are you trying to get rid of?

Comment: (function() {})({
    "Data": {

Comment: Is that the result of a Google API request, or are you scraping that from somewhere?

Comment: Can you post the url for the top array...

Comment: That is from somewhere else...

Comment: whoops forgot to put URL haha....
http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/Quote/json?symbol=AAPL` as the url, leaving out the p in json.

```
<?php
$stock = "FB";
//Obtain Quote Info
//$quote = file_get_contents('http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/Quote/json?symbol='.$stock);

//or with curl
$quote = curl_get('http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/Quote/json?symbol='.$stock);

function curl_get($url){
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

//decode JSON data
$json_output = json_decode(utf8_decode($quote));

$perc = $json_output->Data->ChangePercent;
$last = $json_output->Data->LastPrice;
$date = $json_output->Data->Timestamp;
$name = $json_output->Data->Name;

print_r($json_output);
/*
stdClass Object
(
    [Data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Status] => SUCCESS
            [Name] => Facebook Inc
            [Symbol] => FB
            [LastPrice] => 31.91
            [Change] => -1.12
            [ChangePercent] => -3.3908567968514
            [Timestamp] => Fri May 25 16:00:05 UTC-04:00 2012
            [MarketCap] => 20214729720
            [Volume] => 37189630
            [ChangeYTD] => 0
            [ChangePercentYTD] => 0
            [High] => 32.95
            [Low] => 31.11
            [Open] => 32.9
        )

)*/
?>
```

Comment: Great man that worked for me.  Thank you so much.  Im about 3 days into learning json.  Im grasping it but was stuck on this one.

Comment: APIs that offer jsonp `JSON with padding` normally offer standard json, 99.9% of the time its just remove the p. You should also perhaps use curl to grab the result as it will be slightly faster.

Comment: Yeah i have not jumped into cURL yet.  Do you have an example of what that might look like?

Comment: @DavidMorin Ive updated my answer with a simple curl function.

Comment: Oh excellent.  Thank you man.  im touching on cURL next week.

Answer (score -1):

The code you are using for Google Finance is directly customized to work with the output from the Google Finance API you're using.

Here is the output from Google Finance:

```
// [
{
"id": "296878244325128"
,"t" : "FB"
,"e" : "NASDAQ"
,"l" : "31.91"
,"l_cur" : "31.91"
,"s": "0"
,"ltt":"4:00PM EDT"
,"lt" : "May 25, 4:00PM EDT"
,"c" : "-1.12"
,"cp" : "-3.39"
,"ccol" : "chr"
}
]
```

The part of your code that does:

```
$data = substr($json, 4, strlen($json) -5);
```

is exactly stripping out the unwanted characters from the GF output. For your new output wrapped inside the anonymous function, I suggest the following:

```
<?php
preg_match('/\(function\(\) \{\}\)\((.*)\)/', $input_string, $matches);
$data_json = $matches[1];
$json_output = json_decode($data_json, true); //true = assoc array
$final_json = $json_output['Data'];
```

This will assign a valid json string to the $json variable, where $input_string is the input you listed in your question. And $final_json will contain whatever is inside the Data: property of the original json.

Comment: Im not wanting to use the google finance API anymore as it is going away.  I want to strip away the unwanted characters in the output.  So baaically like my GF code is doing but with this new link.  But i cannot for the life of me get it to work.

Comment: My answer is made for the new output. The four lines of code at the end do exactly what you want.